# crash after printing linked list

Tags: c, crash, linked-list, printf, doubly-linked-list

I have the following struct:

```
struct coords
{
    int x;
    int y;
    struct coords* previous;
    struct coords* next;
};
```

I then have a doubly linked list of these coords (formatted as (x,y)), which should look like this (where head and tail are the start and end of the list):

```
head                                                          tail
(-1, -1) <--> (0, 1) <--> (2, 1) <--> (1, 0) <--> (0, 2) <--> (-1, -1)
```

I want to print this list, so I have the following code:

```
struct coords* iter = head;
while (iter->next != NULL)
      {
          printf("\n [this node: (%d, %d)] -> [next node: (%d), (%d)]", iter->x, iter->y, iter->next->x, iter->next->y);
          iter = iter->next;
      }
printf("done with loop");
```

The output I get is this:

```
[this node: (-1, -1)] -> [next node: (0, 1)]
[this node: (0, 1)] -> [next node: (2, 1)]
[this node: (2, 1)] -> [next node: (1, 0)]
[this node: (1, 0)] -> [next node: (0, 2)]
[this node: (0, 2)] -> [next node: (-1, -1)]
```

which is all correct. However, immediately after printing the last line, my program crashes without printing "done with loop".

Comment: Are you sure the last item has `next` set to null?

Comment: A very simple solution. I somehow overlooked that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the value of tail->next is NULL ?

If not, that's the reason!

Answer (score 0):

How are you doing the insertion of the nodes into the list?  Most likely the next pointer on your -1, -1 node isn't null.  Because it's not null, the null check passes, but when you try to call iter->next->x, the ->x dereferences bogus memory and your program crashes.  easy way to check is to print out the next pointer as well.

```
printf("\n [this node: (%d, %d)] -> [next node: (%d), (%d)], next next= %p", iter->x, iter->y, iter->next->x, iter->next->y, iter->next->next);
```

It should be non-null except for the last line printed, in which case it should be null.

Most insertion code propogates the initial head value, so I would guess that you maybe aren't initializing your head pointer to null when you declare it.